# Disabling rules within an InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

If you need to disable an existing rule in Infopath how do you go about doing that? I am trying to disassociate two items on a form and cant for the life of me find out where to handle that...

Thanks!

Comment: Please, add more information like platform that you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable an existing rule in Infopath, just delete the rule.

As far as I know, there is no action "disable rules" in Infopath, you have to delete it to disable it.